# jquery - stretch background image to fill document rather than window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background, background-image

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch to stretch a background in a good way.

So the issue is that if the content of the document is long enough to cause a scrollbar, then when you scroll, the image stays in the same place (just looks like a stationary background). You can see it in his demo here: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ (this page uses the plugin. Just scroll and notice the background doesn't move).

I'm wondering if there's a way to change the plugin to not use the window height or something and rather use the document height? I've looked, but to no avail. I know this isn't a great idea in the case that the content is long, but it's done on only a single page that doesn't have much content at all. Really the only issues are if the browser real estate (not counting the chrome) is like less than around 650px in height.

Here's the plugin code. Pretty short and well written from what I can tell:
https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/raw/master/jquery.backstretch.js

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem, this was my solution.

```
$(window).resize(bg);
function bg() {
    var imgWidth = 1088, 
        imgHeight = 858,
        imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight,
        bgWidth = $(document).width(),
        bgHeight = bgWidth / imgRatio;

        $('body').css({backgroundPosition: 'top center'});
        if ($(document).width() < imgWidth && $(document).height() < imgHeight && $(document).height() > bgHeight) {
            $('body').css({backgroundSize: 'auto 100%'});
        } else {
            $('body').css({backgroundSize: '100% auto'});
        }
}
bg();
$('body').css({backgroundRepeat: 'repeat-x'});
$('body').css({backgroundImage: 'url("images/bg-state/bg_static2.png")'});
```

Note: It do not stretch on IE due to the code uses the css3 property background-size and you need to set your own width and height of the image in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with scrollable content and a fixed background would be to just use an `<iframe>` or fixing the `<img>` on a layer. Then you wouldn't need to depend on jQuery (which I think is a bit heavy) for something that could be done on the browser without it.

```
<body background="background.png">
    <iframe src="content.html" height="600"/>
</body>
```

Also found another way to do it with layers:

```
<img src="background.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:-1;" />
<div style="position: static;z-index: 1; ">
    content
</div>
```

Comment: You have 2 positions set in the img ?? Fixed and absolute... this is not good!

Comment: good catch (style wise), but technically last one wins so you can set all the `position` property all day long but upon rendering only the last one will count ;)

Answer (score -2):

Without paying respect to the image ratio, I believe you could set `bgHeight` to `$("body").height()`.